# List all packages of incompatible repository using CLI arm64 vs. amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, arm64

On 23.04 amd64 ***apt list | wc -l*** throws me ~70500 packages. I would like to list and count all available 23.04 packages of arm64 architecture for comparison. How can I easily do this in CLI?

Comment: This seems like some kind of homework assignment.